# KeyListener not activating

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener

I can't find what's wrong in my code... I tried debugging by putting in sysouts but it seems the keylistener is the culprit. Why isn't it registering any keypresses?

```
public class Pong extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

public void init() {
    this.resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.addKeyListener(this);

    p1 = new HumanPaddle(1);

    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        p1.setUpAccel(true);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        p1.setDownAccel(true);
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        p1.setUpAccel(false);
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        p1.setDownAccel(false);
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: `KeyListener` is a pain in the ... code. In order to work, the component it is registered to MUST be focusable AND have current keyboard focus. If your were using Swing, we'd recommend using the Key Bindings API, which would help solve the problem.  Since you're using applets, you're going to have additional issues as the applet will need to have focus in the browser as well, which is something you can't control.

Comment: Start by making the component focusable - `setFocusable(true)` then use something like `requestFocusInWindow` in an attempt to draw keyboard focus to the component. I'd recommend putting this in the `start` method AND using a `MouseListener`s `mousePressed` event to call it as well, because this approach is just a hack

Comment: And, applets are dead, they are officially deprecated and are no longer support - it's time to move on

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"the applet will need to have focus in the browser as well, which is something you can't control"* LOL! Tell me about it. If a web page contains two applets and other focusable elements, it's anybody's guess as to whether the focus will go to the applets or web page elements, and if applets, which one (first in HTML, first to load, last to load..). So glad that **applets are dead.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson Try stealing focus from the browser 